# Onfocus shadow not working in IE

Tags: css

Below code is not working in IE..

```
 input:focus,textarea:focus,select:focus
{
  border:1px solid #fafafa;
   -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 6px #007eff;
   -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px #007eff;
  box-shadow:0 0 5px #007eff;
}
```

Instead it is not showing textbox border even.
 Here is the fiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/3cKVp/1/

Comment: Which version of IE? `:focus` is not supported on lower than 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not work in IE 7 or earlier, as you can see on [this](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-focus) page which shows you a compatibility levels for specific browsers.

Comment: @Reddy: You can disable this part for IE and just live without decoration

Comment: @genesis let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1780/discussion-between-prathap-reddy-and-genesis)

Comment: @Reddy Let IE users live without it. It's called "progressive enhacement" when you give newer browsers a better experience than older browsers. See http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/ and http://dowebsitesneedtobeexperiencedexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/

Answer (score 0):

`:focus` pseudoselector and `box-shadow` CSS property is not supported in IE7. To support focus style changes you will have to bind to `focus` and  `blur` events in javascript (possibly using jQuery) and add/remove respectively a CSS style that will indicate a "focused" appearance.